# how to filter within a with operator laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a group of accounts being returned, and each account has a number of relations to it (accounts related to other accounts). The following:

```
return AccountGroup::with(['account.relationships'])
```

Returns accounts with the other accounts that are related to it, the data will then look like this:

```
0: {accountId: 37868, name: "Random", ...}
accountId: 37868"
irdNumber: "72038410"
name: "Random"
relationships: [{relationshipId: 16851, loginId: 506, accountId: 37868, statusId: 1, groupId: 2},…]
0: {relationshipId: 16851, accountId: 37868, statusId: 1}
accountId: 37868
relationshipId: 16851
statusId: 1
1: {relationshipId: 16871, accountId: 37868, statusId: 1}
```

Now I want to return those relationships that have a relationship account id = accountid, i.e. where `accountId = relationship.accountId`

How would i go about doing this? I have read up about `whereColumn` but not sure if that's appropriate...

Relationships is a callable in the account model:

```
public function relationships()
{
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Entities\Security\Relationship\Relationship', 'accountId');
}
```

This then returns an array of relationships against the account in question, I want to filter out the ones that dont have a relationship.accountId = accountId

Comment: Show us how your relationships are defined in the model, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the relationships loaded using `with` using an array syntax:

```php
return AccountGroup::with(['account.relationships' => function ($query) {
   // Filter `account.relationships` according to your needs
   $query->where('accountId', ...);
}])
```

More info here: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

---

Another approach would be to define a custom relationship in the `AccountGroup` model for this specific need:

In your `AccountGroup` model:

```php
public function relationships()
{
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Entities\Security\Relationship\Relationship', 'accountId', 'accountId');
}
```

Then:

```php
return AccountGroup::with(['relationships'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is

```php
whereHas('relationship', function($query) {
    // filter
})
```

https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: This will only return the AccountGroups with a relationship that fulfill the query. From OP question, what I understand is that he wants to query all the `AccountGroup`s, including the relationships that fulfill a specific filter.